# Android Studio not showing logcat info while running the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

As the title says, Android Studio doesn't show me the logcat info while using the emulator. If I connect my device directly, it runs with no problem. What could be the cause? I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3.

Tried everything, Invalidate Cache/Restart LogCat. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: The Logcat tab is absent on the bottom menu at all?

Answer (score 2):

Have you selected here correct device (emulator instead of your phone)?

[image]

Comment: Also, make sure that you have no leftover searches or filters enabled on the same panel, that don't correspond to any valid results anymore.

Comment: Yes, I  already made sure the emulator is selected and not the phone. Even unplugged it. Also I selected the running application but to no avail.